# Spawn bullet at barrel of gun

Tags: rotation, game-maker

I'm making a top-down shooter and the player's gun is offset from the coordinates of the object.  I'm using GameMaker:Studio, so the x and y coords are the center of the object.  The offset of the image is set here:

```
bullet_offset_x = 30;
bullet_offset_y = 28;
```

And here is the code for shooting the gun:

```
var xpos = x + (bullet_offset_x * cos(degtorad(direction))) - (bullet_offset_y * sin(degtorad(direction)));
var ypos = y + (bullet_offset_x * sin(degtorad(direction))) + (bullet_offset_y * cos(degtorad(direction)));

var flash = instance_create(xpos, ypos, obj_flash);

with (flash){
    direction = other.direction;
    image_angle = other.direction;
}
```

I'm using the following formula for placing the muzzle flash:

x' = x*cos(angle) - y*sin(angle)

y' = x*sin(angle) + y*cos(angle)

Therefore:

xpos = x + x' and ypos = x + y'

However, when I run the code, the muzzle flash is correctly positioned when the angle is 0/360, but is off otherwise.  Am I calculating this wrong?

IMAGES:

Correct

[image: Correct]

Incorrect

[image: Incorrect]
[image: Incorrect]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my brain checked out after I finished that much.  I'm about to add pictures

Comment: `0,0` the center of the character and `30,28` would be the end of the gun barrel, correct?

Comment: Yes, the sprite faces right at 0 degres by default and from that position, it is 30,28.  Technically 30,-28 but y increases downwards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `lengthdir_x` and `lengthdir_y` functions, like:

```
var xpos = x + lengthdir_x(offset_distance, offset_angle + image_angle); // or direction
var ypos = y + lengthdir_y(offset_distance, offset_angle + image_angle);

var flash = instance_create(xpos, ypos, obj_flash);

flash.direction = direction;
flash.image_angle = direction;
```

little example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yww6jj51vy6hcxg/bullet_angle.gmk?dl=0)

To calculate the values ​​to be substituted into the formula, you can use [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5zy309cnf39w5l/Calc_lengthdir.exe?dl=0) program. 
Originally it was made in Russian, but I have translated it into English. My English is terrible, but I hope you will be able to understand it.

**upd:** [Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/RelativePosition.gmz) with offsets:

```
var delta_x = 60;
var delta_y = -70;
var angle = point_direction(0, 0, delta_x, delta_y);
var distance = point_distance(0, 0, delta_x, delta_y);

var xpos = x + lengthdir_x(distance, image_angle + angle);
var ypos = y + lengthdir_y(distance, image_angle + angle);
var obj = instance_create(xpos, ypos, obj_flash);
obj.image_angle = image_angle;
```

Answer (score 0):

When your sprite has an angle of 0, your muzzle flash still at an angle of `invtan(28/30)` in relation to the sprite. Therefore, the angle that the flash must be placed at in relation to the rotation of the sprite can be given by

```
flashRotation = spriteRotationDegrees - invtan(28/30) \\you can change this to radians
```

Once that is found, the positions can be found by:

```
var x_pos = sprite_x_pos + Math.Sqrt(28^2 + 30^2)cos(flashRotation);
var y_pos = sprite_y_pos + Math.Sqrt(28^2 + 30^2)sin(flashRotation);
```

The actual angle of rotation of the flash (which way it points) will be the same angle as the sprite.
You may need to play with the flashRotaion equation depending upon which way is counted as a positive rotation.

Comment: Now it works around Quadrant 2, but all other quadrants are incorrect.  Here's the angle code I used: `var flash_angle = direction - radtodeg(arctan2(bullet_offset_y, bullet_offset_x));` and I then replaced all instances of `direction` with `flash_angle`

Comment: With, y increasing down, try `flash_angle = direction + radtodeg(arctan2(bullet_offset_y, bullet_offset_x));`. Also, I forgot that if the rotation is between 90 and 270 degrees, you need to add `pi` to the flash_angle. Note, this angle does not give the direction that the flash needs to point, it is only used to get the x and y offsets

Comment: Since flash_angle is in degrees, would that mean add 180 instead?

Comment: Lol all good.  It doesn't seem to be working, but the math all looks right.  I'm going to try and calculate a longhand formula myself and see if that works, then use yours to try and simplify it.  I feel like it's just a quirk with GameMaker with how they handle direction or movement.